# Access violation on RAD Studio 2010 where enter to project options

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, access-violation

Maybe anyone can tell us why is this violation happening.

We work with Emabrcadero RAD Studio 2010. Sometimes, the project becomes corrupted and we can't enter to Project Options. Is we try to enter, it shows the next error message:

```
Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000
```

If we try to enter it at a second time, it shows:

```
Access violation at address 209931F1 in module 'coreide140.bpl'. Read of address 00000000
```

From this point, ALL projects throws the same error until we restart the IDE. When we restart it, projects work fine except the corrupted project. The only solution we've found is to create a new project and copy the units there (so tedious).

Today, it happened to all the projects from a specific folder (the other times it only happened to a single project).

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Deinstalling all third party components - one by one. After uninstalling each component check to see if the problem persists. This can narrow finding the faulty component (if this was the problem of course)
2. Install madExcept / EurekaLog. They integrate with the IDE. Restart the IDE. Open some project's options. If the error persists you can see the callstack and eventually find the reason for the problem
3. Use [SysInternal's Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and capture events between opening project's options and the exception you see. Analyse the dump - there may be faulting or corrupted dll/bpl
4. Repair IDE installation
5. [Open support case at Embarcadero](https://support.embarcadero.com/Forms/product/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: We've reinstalled all components and now it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable windows firewall service. I don't know why, but it solved the same problem.